# Windows Media Player will not play .WMV from link in IE11

Tags: windows, video, internet-explorer-11, windows-media-player, wmv

I click on a link to a .WMV file in IE11, Windows Media Player opens and gives me the following error:

"Windows media player cannot connect to the server. The server name might not be correct, the server might not be available or your proxy settings might not be correct"

The same link works in firefox but not in IE11

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?